# Find if function has finished looping firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, I have been dealing with something I really need some help with, so I am here. I have a simple function where it loops through firebase and adds data to arrays. Here is the problem, I need to know where the function has finished looping. I honestly need some help figuring this out, so here is an example.

```
func getUsers() {
 let ref = Database.database.reference()
 if let myAget = self.myAgel {
            ref.child("newUsers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshoter) in
                if let valuer = snapshoter.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    for (one,_) in valuer {
                       checkCount.append("one")
                        ref.child("users").child(one).child("age").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
                            if let agerti = snap.value as? Int {
                         if myAget - agerti <= 1 && myAget - agerti >= -1 {
                                    print("Add this user")     
                                  }
                            }             
                         })
                       }
                   }
                 print("now do something with those users")
               }
            })
      }
}
```

**Console Prints :

now do something with those users

Add this user

Add this user

Add this user

Add this user

AS you can see, the problem is I want to call a function after I simply check if the users age is close to yours : +- 1 yr. How can I have it print "now do something..." after "add the user". Thank you so much!, Please respond if you have anything helpful at all, I am in need of anything.

Comment: Look at using a `DispatchGroup` and `dispatchGroupNotify`

Comment: I totally agree, but where would I call dispatchGroup.leave() in this scenario, that is my struggle.

Comment: Where you have the print "Add this user"

Comment: but what if I need to add multiple users? I don't stop after 1, but rather until the for loop Is done, or there are 40users added. Btw thank you for answering my question.

Comment: You enter the dispatch group as many times as you need and leave for each enter.

Comment: So should I enter the dispatchGroup when I first call the function, or when I call the for loop (inside loop) ?. Thanks again btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `DispatchGroup` for this.  You need to `enter` the dispatch group before you start each unit of asynchronous work and `leave` when that unit is complete.  You can establish as closure to be executed when all work is complete using `notify`.

```
func getUsers() {
    let ref = Database.database.reference()
    if let myAget = self.myAgel {

        ref.child("newUsers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshoter) in
            if let valuer = snapshoter.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
                for (one,_) in valuer {
                    dispatchGroup.enter()
                    checkCount.append("one")
                    ref.child("users").child(one).child("age").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
                        if let agerti = snap.value as? Int {
                            if myAget - agerti <= 1 && myAget - agerti >= -1 {
                                print("Add this user")     
                            }
                        } 
                        dispatchGroup.leave()        
                     })
                 }
                 dispatchGroup.notify {
                    print("now do something with those users")
                 }
             }

         })
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, accepted right now but will test it in the morning, looks good, thanks again.

Comment: @Paulw11 I used this and it works well however I notice gcd doesn't have a cancel method. How would you do the same thing above using OperationQueues?

Comment: @LanceSamaria You would need to ensure that `dispatchGroup.leave()` was executed in some way when the operation completes. For example, you could put the `dispatchGroup.leave()` in the `NSOperation`'s `completionBlock`.

Comment: @Paulw11 what happens if you want to leave early and you don’t want dispatchGroup.notify to run? For example if I have an arr of 5 urls, I want to loop through and display them using URLSession, once done I can use notify to display them all in a tableView. But if there is an error I want to cancel the entire operation and I don’t want notify to run and I don’t want to display anything. I have to use .leave() in the error to balance out the calls but the group will still continue to the next iteration until done. Should I put the error’s .leave() in an NSOperationBlock?

Comment: Best to set a flag and check it in your `notify` closure.

Comment: @Paulw11 that’s exactly what I did. I put a flag in the error and set it to true then inside notify I check if flag is true or false. If false (no error) then proceed to show images but if the flag is true (error) then don’t show the images. I thought there was possibly a better way. Amazing Apple didn’t simply create a cancel() to stop notify from running. As usual thanks for the help!